# How can i reload a div without refreshing page in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I am creating a **CRUD Application** using **Ajax** in **Laravel 8**. And the problem is I want to reload my table using ajax without reloading the whole page but it's not reloading. I tried a lot of ways but it doesn't work. How can I do that?
[image]

This is my code in **books.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Bootstrap Datatables</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.12.1/datatables.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-center fw-bold">Bootstrap Datatable</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" id="createNewBook" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                    data-bs-target="#addmodel">
                    Add Record
                </button>
            </div>
            <table id="datatables" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Book_ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Book_Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Auther</th>
                        <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">

                    @foreach ($books as $row)
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{ $row->id }}</th>
                        <td>{{$row->title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->author }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id="' . $row->id . '"
                                data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editBook">Edit</a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id="' . $row->id . '"
                                data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteBook">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addmodel" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Book</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="bookForm" name="bookForm" class="form-horizontal">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" name="book_id" id="book_id">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title"
                                placeholder="Enter Title" value="" maxlength="50" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-3">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Author</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <textarea id="author" name="author" required="" placeholder="Enter Author"
                                class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 mt-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn" value="create">Save changes
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.12.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#datatables").DataTable({});
$("#bookForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var title = $("#title").val();
    var author = $("#author").val();
    var _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{route('book.add')}}",
        data: {
            title: title,
            author: author,
            _token: _token
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response) {
                $("#bookForm")[0].reset();
                $("#addmodel").modal("hide");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#saveBtn").click(function() {
        $("#tbody").load("#tbody");
    });

});
</script>
```

And this is my code in **Controller**

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Book;

class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $books = Book::all();
        return view('books', compact('books'));
    }

    public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $book = new Book();
        $book->title = $request->title;
        $book->author = $request->author;
        $book->save();
        return response()->json($book);
    }
}
```

So how can I do that, please help me out...

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: @TreyCopeland no, there is no console error.

Answer (score 2):

This question already has an answer by another user but i can repeat it here for you.

```
<script>
$('#tbody').load(document.URL +  ' #tbody');
</script>
```

Comment: it works but all the table formatting is disturbed when I use this method

Comment: It's because the tbody loads separately. Try reload whole table if it's not annoying for your visitors.

Answer (score 1):

replace your ajax with this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{route('book.add')}}",
    data: {
        title: title,
        author: author,
        _token: _token
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if (response) {
            $("#bookForm")[0].reset();
            $('#tbody').load(document.URL +  ' #tbody');
            $("#addmodel").modal("hide");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Works fine when you tried it on the entire table or div covering the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

**I hope I'm not too much late but u can do something like below:-**

1. Create a page **load.blade.php** in views folder
2. In the **Controller** code below

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Book;

class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $books = Book::all();
        return view('books', compact('books'));
    }

    public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $book = new Book();
        $book->title = $request->title;
        $book->author = $request->author;
        $book->save();
        $html=view('load',compact($book))->render();
        return response()->json(['html'=>$html]);
    }
}
```

3. In **load.blade.php** file code below

```
@foreach ($book as $row)
<tr>
   <th scope="row">{{ $row->id }}</th>
   <td>{{$row->title }}</td>
   <td>{{ $row->author }}</td>
   <td>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id="' . $row->id . '"
                                data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editBook">Edit</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id="' . $row->id . '"
                                data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteBook">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>

@endforeach
```

4. In the **Ajax** code below

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{route('book.add')}}",
    data: {
        title: title,
        author: author,
        _token: _token
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if (response) {
            $("#bookForm")[0].reset();
            $('#tbody').html(response.html);
            $("#addmodel").modal("hide");
        }
    }
});
```

**I hope this helps, if any query do ask.**

Answer (score 0):

Someone already answered with this, with a small problem.

Here's a working fix:

```
<script>
$('#tbody').load(document.URL +  ' #tbody tr');
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use this for eg.

`window.newSetInterval = window.setInterval; window.setInterval = function(func, interval) { var interval = newSetInterval(func, interval); }`

Comment: what does this do?

what does setting an interval have to do with refreshing the table without reloading the page?

the question is looking for a laravel/ajax solution, not a plain JS function.

also, please provide some content to you answers to help people who are seriously looking for help.